# SnappyData data type compatibility

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, compatibility, type-conversion, snappydata

as I am creating a new database and importing the schema structure from Postgresql to SnappyData I am dealing with the problem about what to use to replace each data type.
First what to use to have compatible data with timestamp, real, double, long (coordinates), and string?
I searched in the help and documentation but did not find a good explanation about it...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like all data types you mention are covered here - https://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/reference/sql_reference/create-table/

Comment: yes thanks... I did explain it wrongly... will come back with a better explanation...